# Run-time error when canceling a 'Save As' dialog displayed via VBA

Tags: vba, save, word-2007

I have a macro that formats a document in a certain way, and then saves it, using `ActiveDocument.Save`.

However, sometimes the document is not already saved, and in some cases I don't want to save it. Unfortunately, clicking 'Cancel' when the 'Save As' dialogue is displayed is causing a run-time error (4198) -

> Command failed

Does anyone know how I can prevent this from happening? Thanks.

Comment: So in some cases you do want to allow `SaveAs`?

Comment: Yes, it should be up to the user. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated to handle your revised question.

Comment: ...however, after some more reading, I'm not at all confident that this can be achieved. It seems that I will either have to go down the no SaveAs at all route (perhaps warn the user to save manually), or the `On Error` route. Sadly, it's got to be `On Error` to achieve what I want, which is not a good thing!

Comment: No .... read my updated post :)

Comment: Just have - tested and working, many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Updated: Now*

*1. Tests if the file has been previously saved or not*
 *2. If the fileis unsaved, a controlled process is used to show the `SaveAs` dialog
    to either save the file, or handle the `Cancel`*

**code**

```
Dim bSave As Boolean
If ActiveDocument.Path = vbNullString Then
bSave = Application.Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs).Show
If Not bSave Then MsgBox "User cancelled", vbCritical
Else
ActiveDocument.Save
End If
```

Comment: Thanks @bredttdj, but I'm afraid this doesn't work. `Compile error: Expected Function or variable`, with `.save` being indicated as the offending piece of code.

Comment: @DavidGard while the code worked for me without any errors, I should have tested the existence of `Path` not `Saved`. Pls try the above code.

Comment: Apologies, I mis-read your code. `.saved` does work, however I'm afraid you have misinterpreted my question (editing now to make it clearer). Some times the user will want to save previously unsaved documents using the Save As dialogue, and sometimes that will not. So unfortunately skipping it if the document is not already saved is not an option. I realise I can then ask the user if they wish to save, but that still gives them the option of pressing 'Cancel', so I'd be back to square one. Thanks.

Comment: @brettdj - Tested and working, many thanks for your assistance in figuring this out.

Answer (score 3):

Please try the following by adding some error handling instructions:

```
On Error Resume Next    'to omit error when cancel is pressed
   ActiveDocument.Save

If Err.Number <> 0 Then   'optional, to confirmed that is not saved
   MsgBox "Not saved"      
End If
On Error GoTo 0         'to return standard error operation
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. While I understand that you an skip errors in VBA, I'd prefer to understand why the error is being thrown if possible, and work around it that way. I will use this method if required to do so though.

Comment: What I know is that VBA doesn't provide simple solutions for some user actions like your example or very popular problem with Cancel button for `Application.Inputbox` in Excel VBA. Therefore some other VBA implementations are reqired...

Comment: @kaz Jaw That is incorrect, there is a simple solution without error handling.

Comment: @KazJaw - Don't I know it! Some things that should be simple really are not. And as great as error handling is, VBA seems to rely on it far to much for some tasks that really should have a built in 'get out'. I have implemented the above for now, but if you do even come across another way to do it, I'd appreciate it if you could post it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for vsto developers, please go here

```
    if (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Path == String.Empty)
        {
            Word.Dialog dlg;
            Object timeout = 3000;
            dlg = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Dialogs[
                Word.WdWordDialog.wdDialogFileSaveAs];
            int result = dlg.Display(ref timeout);
        }
        else
        {
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Save();
        }
```

The result will store which button is pressed (0- cancel, 1- ok, 2- close)